# Simultaneous optimization 2

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Consider a continuous and differentiable function $f(x,y,z)$ with $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$. For each $(y,z)$, there exists a unique $x_1(y,z)$ that maximizes $f(x,y,z)$. For each $(x,z)$, there exists a unique $y_1(x,z)$ that maximizes $f(x,y,z)$. $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial z}>0$, $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x \partial z}>0$

Hypothesis: $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial z}>0$

Can you hint me towards the Theorem that shows this or sketch a proof?

Do I need $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x \partial y}>0$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial y \partial z}>0$ on top of this?

Comment: You could suppress $y$ from the question: it plays no role. Well, maybe it could play a role if you add conditions with partial derivatives on $y$, but that does not feel like the simplest thing to do.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni: Thanks. I do not see yet that I can ignore y. The optimal y and optimal x could be functions of z. Thus could interact with each other. But first things first, "Is the statement correct"? If I can drop y, it is actually quite simple, you are right. But why can I drop?

Comment: Now the statement may be true, although I have no time right now to look at it, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Long comment) Variable $y$ can be dropped from the problem, by reasoning on restrictions $f_{y_0}$ of $f$ to any $y_0$, with $f_{y_0}(x,z) = f(x,y_0,z)$.

Then:

- $f_{y_0}$ is continuous and differentiable, because $f$ is.
- For each $z$ there is a unique $x_{1,y_0}(z)$ that maximises $f_{y_0}(x,z)$: that's the $x_1(y,z)$ that maximises $f(x,y_0,z)$.
- $\frac {\partial f_{y_0}(x,z)} {\partial z} = \frac {\partial f(x,y,z)} {\partial z}$, and same for all other partials on $x$ and $z$.
- $\frac {\partial x_{1,y_0}} {\partial z} (z) = \frac {\partial x_1} {\partial z} (y_0,z)$.

Of course the idea is to drop entirely $y$. I only mentionned $y_0$ above for clarity.